# How to store search keyword or browsing history in database

Tags: database-design, performance, phpmyadmin, web-service, query-performance

I'm making my final year project. Which is a website.
Things I can't do:

1. Store the browsing history of users between their login and logout session on the site. 
   Or
2. Store the search keywords.

But I dont know how to do it. Is there any query or functions that I can use???
I'm using xampp server.

I'm really stuck in this phase and don't know how to do it.
One of my friend told me it's IMPOSSIBLE.
Does anyone have a possible solution rather than just IMPOSSIBLE.
Please help.

Comment: Which part are you stuck on?  A good database design to hold the data?  We need more information about what data you want to hold and how it is related to each other (and probable queries).  If you are looking for how to get the data from your site to the database then that should be straightforward.  Just insert events where you want them in your site and push that data to the database.  You won't (or shouldn't be able to) get data from the user's browser except for while it's on your site; that would fall under hacking and exploits.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just want the URLs in my database that users have browsed when they are logged in the system..Is it possible??

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm not sure just what you are looking for here.

Since you are using xampp you can manage user sessions in php using their [session functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php).

Apache also has it's own [domain logs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/logs.html) which you can keep for however long.

You can also use redis for [session management](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-redis-server-as-a-session-handler-for-php-on-ubuntu-16-04) if you are ok with the session information being volatile.

In general I don't see this as a database question, and suggest moving this question to one of the other SE sites such as Stack Overflow or Server Fault.